# Android REST Tutorial / Sample Project

Tags: java, android

Coming from Windows Phone/Store development, I'm used to a lot of tutorials and sample projects on things. I can't, for the life of me, find any good resources on how to create an Android app which interacts with a real REST service. Just a simple app which talks to some random API to help people see how to write Android apps.  An app which just hits an API and throws some decent looking view elements on the display would be great.

In Windows land, typically these resources are plentiful and offer best practices, project layout suggestions, etc.  Since Android has a greater market share, I expected to find resources easier, but apparently not. Any help would be appreciated. My current setup is using Android Studio.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/03/android-hosting-php-mysql-restful-services-to-digitalocean/

Comment: What a terrible example...

Comment: You are looking for this on REST API communication http://stackoverflow.com/a/26573636/2413303 and if you want to look into something more advanced, here is a nifty project with sources and everything https://github.com/vyshane/rex-weather and don't forget the official guide http://developer.android.com/training/index.html and also use Otto http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html and ButterKnife http://www.tikalk.com/better-buttered-look-butter-knife-view-injection-library-android/

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - thanks! The github link looks good and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is one: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android--cms-21587

At the 9 point you will find the class used for the httpCall. This is just the first one I found looking on Google for "meteo app android tutorial" . It seems good.

Comment: Thank you! This is along the lines I am looking for.

Comment: i have tested your code that is simple weather-APP. but code has many bugs and when you try to run that app then it will going to crash and no crash record found...  so will not recommend anyone to use that code .totally wast of time.