# Stick with volley or try some new libraries?

Tags: android, android-networking

I have already done one project with volley and gson integrated. Now I am going to start new project with networking requirements. The requirement has login, signup with facebook, google etc and has a game part which needs to be real time(need to hit the api). Considering this, should I stick with volley and gson or should I try out retrofit or spring for android which supports oauth login to facebook, twitter etc or robospice? I am confused.

Please suggest with valid reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using Retrofit for your networking requirements.

I am using Retrofit library with REST Api and it works pretty fast.

please look at : **[Using Retrofit in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android)**

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use default classes then the libraries for transmitting the data. Libraries have some restriction. and you can use the gson library . no issue in that to use the gson.