# RestAdapter (retrofit) not resolving in android

Tags: android, retrofit

So I am trying to use Retrofit for my project. As the site says I have included 
`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'` in `build.gradle`. I was reading the tutorials from this [link](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/android-retrofit-images-tutorial/) . I want to do something similar like this

```
final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://services.hanselandpetal.com").build();

        api flowerapi = restadapter.create(api.class);

        flowerapi.getData(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Flower> flowers, Response response) {
                flowerList = flowers;
                adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,flowerList);
                //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }
```

in my project ie make some calls to an API. But restadapter just doesn't get `resolved`. On hovering on it it simply says `symbol can't be resolved`. What is happening here ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have two options:

#### 1) Use stable Retrofit 1

This has the `RestAdapter` class you need.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

#### 2) Migrate to Retrofit 2

The `RestAdapter` class was renamed to `Retrofit` and the API was completely remade. Read more in [Jake Wharton's presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015).

<s>`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'`</s>

As of June 30 2016 the latest version is  2.1.0 obtained by

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

Please check http://square.github.io/retrofit/ for updates.

Answer (score 29):

There is a change in the API in version 2. This is how you do it in this version:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Please refer here for more information: [Retrofit 2 home page](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

and these slides: [Retrofit 2 presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run your code you need to use older version of Retrofit.

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'`

But you are using

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
```

So you need to change your code like this.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
.build();`
```

for complete documentation please check [RetroFit square](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

In Retrofit 2.0, Converter is not included in the package anymore. You need to plug a Converter in yourself or Retrofit will be able to accept only the String result. As a result, Retrofit 2.0 doesn't depend on Gson anymore.

If you want to accept json result and make it parse into DAO, you have to summon Gson Converter as a separate dependency.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

And plug it in through addConverterFactory. Please note that RestAdapter is now also renamed to Retrofit.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://api.nuuneoi.com/base/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

more info: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en