# Retrofit 1.9 RestAdapter Cannot Resolve Symbol in Android Studio

Tags: android, retrofit, android-library, okhttp, android-async-http

I'm following [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client/) and have tried with many more and I always get error: `Cannot resolve symbol` for RestAdapter. So I googled and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424184/restadapter-retrofit-not-resolving-in-android) with answer came up which say to include `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'` which I already have in my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0' //As you can see here
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

}
```

This is the class and method calling the error:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://your.api-base.url";

    private static RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **remove** -->  **compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'** from dependencies into gradle.build file.

**Reason** is that you are **using** Retrofit different version at same time which are **1.9** and **2.0**, which wont work.

Hope it helps to you and others and set my answer as verified so others can get helps.