# success and failure methods not being called in retrofit

Tags: android, asynchronous, callback, retrofit

I am new to retrofit and android programming, need help with the below:

I have the following code for calling  a registration method-

```
Api.getClient().sendRegistrationDetails(username, email, password, gender, new Callback<RegisterUserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(RegisterUserResponse registerUserResponse, Response response) {
                if (registerUserResponse.getSuccess() == "false"){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response_active.replace("<false>",""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (registerUserResponse.getSuccess() == "true"){

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    User user = new User("a","aa","mal",1);
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response_active.replace("<true>",""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response_active.replace("<true>",""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The  Api class as

```
public class Api {

    public static ApiInterface getClient() {

        // change your base URL
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://192.168.1.105") //Setting the Root URL
                .build(); //Finally building the adapter

        //Creating object for our interface
        ApiInterface api = adapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
        return api;
    }
}
```

and the ApiInterface as

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/app_dashboard/JSON/register.php")
    public void sendRegistrationDetails(@Field("username") String username, @Field("email") String email,
                                            @Field("password") String password, @Field("gender") String gender,
                                            Callback<RegisterUserResponse> callback);


}
```

But when I call the  **Api.getClient().sendRegistrationDetails** the two overridden methods *success* and *failure* they are not being called. 
Can someone pls explain why this is ? and what is the solution to this.
Thank you!

Comment: you are using very old code i guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestAdapter (retrofit) not resolving in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424184/restadapter-retrofit-not-resolving-in-android)

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif yes, is there a better solution available for this or a new code?

Comment: kindly go through [Retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Not a duplicate I guess, my other callback methods on the same base are working as fine, only issue is with this, the success method is never being called, the block inside this methods never run.

Comment: you need to upgrade your code