# How to link Android app to a website for registrations for an event?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-json

I'm developing an app for the college fest. The website is under development and the website will have links for registering to various events happening in the fest.
On the app end...

1. The App is gonna ask for Name Email id and DOB the first time that it is executed, and this data is stored.
2. I'm gonna create an Interface with a list of all the events and when a specific event is opened It will have a register button.

Now I wanna know how to send all the data collected in *part 1* and the event id from *part 2* to the official website.
(Name email id and dob being strings)

Comment: use `aysntask` and `json` to collect data and parse it to server

Comment: no, do not use AsyncTask. Your website should be service oriented and should offer a REST api. Android side, use Retrofit to communicate with this API and to do what you need.

Comment: Retrofit is easy to use Here is a Link for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android

Comment: Thank you all.. I'll try Retrofit