# Add multiple key paramaters in retrofit android

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

I want to add duplicate key paramaters in retrofit. 
For example: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1&ei=2&ei=3&ei=4&ej=1&ej=2&ej=3&ek=1&ek=2&ek=3&el=1&el=2&el=3.

These key parameters are adding dynamically.
How to resolve this problem.
Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Retrofit in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` like;

```
Call<YourResponseType> yourFunc(@Query("gfe_rd") String value, @Query("ei") ArrayList<String> eiValues, @Query("ej") ArrayList<String> eJvalues,...);
```

it will work like;

http://yourUrl.com/gfe_rd=cr&ei=1&ei=2...

or you can do it with using `path` and a `for`.

```
String path = "/?";
for (int i = 0; i < yourQueryCount ; i ++ ){
    if (i == 0)
        path += "gfe_rd" + yourValue;
    else if ( i < 5)
        path += "ei=" + yourDynamicValueArrayForEi[i];
    else if ( i < 7)
        path += "ej=" + yourDynamicValueArrayForEj[i];
    .
    .
    .

    if (i < yourQueryCount-1)
     path += "&";
}
```

and give that path to your retrofit function;

```
@GET("{yourPath}")
Call<YourResponseType> yourFunc(@Path("yourPath") String path);
```