# POST data to server from android using session

Tags: android

I want to ask, I have session data and I want to post the session data to server.. I am using JsonArrayRequest..

Below is my code:

```js
// untuk menampilkan semua data pada listview
        private void callVolley(){
        itemList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        session.getLocalSession(LocalSession.KEY_USERNAME);
        // membuat request JSON
        JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url_select, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Data item = new Data();

                        item.setId(obj.getString(TAG_ID));
                        item.setNama(obj.getString(TAG_NAMA));
                        item.setAlamat(obj.getString(TAG_ALAMAT));

                        // menambah item ke array
                        itemList.add(item);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // notifikasi adanya perubahan data pada adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // menambah request ke request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
    }
```

Please somebody help me, where I can post the data....

this session in android:

session.getLocalSession(LocalSession.KEY_USERNAME);

I am using this code and showing all the data, I mean I just want to show some data with parameter session

JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url_select, new Response.Listener()

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a concrete example: What does it show, What do you want ist to show.

Comment: do you use volley library?

Comment: at the moment, the all data showing...but i want just some data with condition like select * table_master where username=key_username.

Comment: yes i using volley liblary

Comment: Please use Retrofit check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android/47516986#47516986

Comment: Please use Retrofit check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android/47516986#47516986

Comment: can u help me i just want to know how to send the session data to url_select using my code...i so confused...T_T

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using volley and creating instance of JsonArrayRequest, so you direct pass your array with JsonArrayReuest constructor please see the below code snippet.

```
 public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray yourArray,
                        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
            errorListener);
}
```

Comment: where i can send the session data ? "session.getLocalSession(LocalSession.KEY_USERNAME);" ?

Comment: you can override getParams methods to upload your session data, or you can create array of your data and pass your array with JsonArrayRequest