# GSON from remote JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to get a json file from remote host and parsing it via GSON.

Therefore I'm calling my function

```
private void initData() {
   placeArrayList = PlaceRepository.getPlaceList();
}
```

In my PlaceRepository-class

```
     public static ArrayList<Place> getPlaceList() {
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, new  TypeToken<ArrayList<Place>>(){}.getType());
}
```

and the referenced json is a static string:

```
  static String json = "[\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"id\":\"GardensByTheBay\",\n" + ...
```

Thats absoluty working. 
But now I would like to use remote json data from my server.

I'm sure that I have to use something like asynctask, right? Because I tried to load the json file and it failed with an NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi ! You can have a look ate OkHttpClient : http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Well, I think you should also take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26500036/6413377)