# How to show a list in Android by using retrofit library?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I have to show A list in an Activity

MY API key is:

http://api.cuidadotechnologies.com/NSSPL/leave_dtls.php

Using GSON converter and retrofit library. 
this API throws response in JSON like this

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "response_data": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "uid": "USER00000003",
      "reason": "Test",
      "type": "Plan Leave",
      "SataDate": "2018-09-18",
      "EndDate": "2018-09-25",
      "ApprovedBy": "USER00000002",
      "ApprovedDate": "2018-09-18",
      "Status": "REJECTED",
      "Remarks": "Test Reject"
    },
    {
      "id": "13",
      "uid": "USER00000003",
      "reason": "Wedding",
      "type": "Plan Leave",
      "SataDate": "2018-01-28",
      "EndDate": "2018-02-05",
      "ApprovedBy": "USER00000002",
      "ApprovedDate": "2018-09-18",
      "Status": "APPROVED",
      "Remarks": "Ok"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am novice in this method please help me to do this step by step.

Comment: You need to create model class as per response. And receive response in retorfit's callback.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow! Request you to please use Google before posting a question. A simple search leads here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android

Comment: neither GSON nor Retrofit has anything to do with showing anything. Retrofit is made to perform network requests, GSON - to convert JSON <--> Model. What exactly is a problem for you? Don't expect us just to do your job instead of you.

Comment: Show some skills  @MonodipRoyChowdhury

Comment: If you are novice, use youtube. You can find many videos which do step by step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Retrofit in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use use POJO classes for converting JSON into classes. Use below website to convert JSON to POJO.

> http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

After that you can use Retrofit to call API and get response. Get reference from this site : https://square.github.io/retrofit/

After you convert into classes you can use Gson Methods for conversion.

```
SomeModelClass responseModel = new Gson().fromJson(response, SomeModelClass.class);
```

You can use this `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` retrofit method to directly convert response into class model if you don't want to do it manually.

And finally you can Create adapter using [ViewHolder Pattern](https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2016/12/android-viewholder-pattern.html) and use that adapter with [RecyclerView](https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2016/12/working-with-recyclerview-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..
make retrofit object..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "http://api.cuidadotechnologies.com/NSSPL/";
public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}



private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}

}
```

make interface for api calling.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("leave_dtls.php")
Call<ResponseData> getData();
}
```

make pojo class for response.

```
public class ResponseDataItem{

@SerializedName("Status")
private String status;

@SerializedName("uid")
private String uid;

@SerializedName("reason")
private String reason;

@SerializedName("ApprovedDate")
private String approvedDate;

@SerializedName("Remarks")
private String remarks;

@SerializedName("ApprovedBy")
private String approvedBy;

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("type")
private String type;

@SerializedName("EndDate")
private String endDate;

@SerializedName("SataDate")
private String sataDate;

public void setStatus(String status){
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatus(){
    return status;
}

public void setUid(String uid){
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getUid(){
    return uid;
}

public void setReason(String reason){
    this.reason = reason;
}

public String getReason(){
    return reason;
}

public void setApprovedDate(String approvedDate){
    this.approvedDate = approvedDate;
}

public String getApprovedDate(){
    return approvedDate;
}

public void setRemarks(String remarks){
    this.remarks = remarks;
}

public String getRemarks(){
    return remarks;
}

public void setApprovedBy(String approvedBy){
    this.approvedBy = approvedBy;
}

public String getApprovedBy(){
    return approvedBy;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate){
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getEndDate(){
    return endDate;
}

public void setSataDate(String sataDate){
    this.sataDate = sataDate;
}

public String getSataDate(){
    return sataDate;
}
```

}

final response..

```
public class ResponseData {

@SerializedName("response_data")
private List<ResponseDataItem> responseData;

@SerializedName("status")
private int status;

public void setResponseData(List<ResponseDataItem> responseData){
    this.responseData = responseData;
}

public List<ResponseDataItem> getResponseData(){
    return responseData;
}

public void setStatus(int status){
    this.status = status;
}

public int getStatus(){
    return status;
}
```

}

called api into fragment or activity like this way..

```
 ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseData> responseDataCall=apiInterface.getData();
    responseDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null && response!=null){
                List<ResponseDataItem> data=response.body().getResponseData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```