# Read Url and get json and set param in json with android and java and get value of json and read it

Tags: java, android, json

Hello i have a qustion

How can I Read Url and get json  and set param in json with android and java and get value of json and read it??

please help me thanks

Comment: Hi Amir, please present what you've tried so far and the errors you're getting. There's nothing to go off of here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use retrofit lib to consume rest api json,

please see this answer

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android][1]